# tensorflow tf.pad shape of output

Tags: python, tensorflow, pad

I have this function:

```
def resize_image(input_layer, counter ,width):

    shape = input_layer.get_shape().as_list()

    H = tf.cast((width * shape[2] / shape[1]),  tf.int32)
    print (H)
    resized_images = tf.image.resize_images(input_layer, [width, H], tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)
    print (resized_images)
    pad_diff = width - H
    padd_images = tf.pad(resized_images, [[0, 0], [0, pad_diff], [0, 0], [0, 0]] , 'CONSTANT')
    return padd_images, counter
```

When I run this :

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

I = tf.random_uniform([15, 15, 13, 5], minval = -5, maxval = 10, dtype = tf.float32) 
padd_images, counter = resize_image(I, 1, 5)
print (I)
print(padd_images)
sess.run(padd_images)
```

I get this:

```
Tensor("Cast/x:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("ResizeBicubic:0", shape=(15, 5, 4, 5), dtype=float32)
Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(15, 15, 13, 5), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Pad:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, ?), dtype=float32)
```

Why there are `?` in the shape of `padd_images`? Is there a way to know its shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a the line

```
H = tf.cast((width * shape[2] / shape[1]),  tf.int32)
```

Here you're defining a tensor. Thus when you compute:

```
pad_diff = width - H
```

you're defining an operation into the graph.

Thus you don't know at compile time what the `pad_diff` value is, but you'll now it only at runtime.

Since you don't need to have `H` as a tensor, just use the regular python cast operation, changing thus `H` with

```
H = int(width * shape[2] / shape[1])
```

In this way, the next operations that use `H` are executed within the python environment and thus the value are known at "compile time".

After that you'll see:

```
Tensor("Pad:0", shape=(15, 6, 4, 5), dtype=float32)
```